# Using RStudio "Run" Command Line With The readline() Function

Tags: r, rstudio, readline

I'm looking into having some user interaction in my code using RStudio. However, I'm running into some issues with the behavior of the command line in conjunction with the `readline()` function. Here's an example to illustrate my issue:

```
x <- 2
y <- 2
if (x == 2) { x <- readline("Put your x here: ") 
} else { x <- 3 }
if (y == 2) { print("Something.")}
```

If I highlight this and hit "run" (or ctrl-alt-b at the end) to run line by line in the command line, I run into unexpected behavior shown here in the command line:

```
> x <- 2
> y <- 2
> if (x == 2) { x <- readline("Put your x here: ") 
+ } else { x <- 3 }
Put your x here: if (y == 2) { print("Something.")}
```

Notice that on line 5, it skips right over the "Put your x here: " prompt (I did not input anything) and continues to the next line. Please do also note, however, when I "source" this code, the issue does not happen and the command line runs as expected (prompts me and waits until I input something).

Overall, this is a minor issue, but for testing purposes, it would be a major help to be able to run my user interaction code without having to source the entire file. Thanks for in advance!

Comment: RStudio's preview version supports customizing keyboard shortcuts, and it's expected that there will be shorcuts for user-defined snippets too. When this gets implemented, maybe you can pass the selected test to a function that saves it as a file, sources it and then deletes the file. I wrote the function but it's not useful without the shortcut.

Comment: I was thinking I could run the code up to the point where the interaction happens, then open a new file, paste the interaction code and just source that file to test it (which I have not tried yet), but thanks for the tip on the upcoming version.

Comment: I have the same issue. I guess nothing has been implemented from that far November 2012! :)